# How to do parsing of Elapsed time in seconds in linux

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk, gawk

I want to do parsing of Elapsed time in seconds .Time formats given below:

```
1) 3 day 18h
2) 3 day
3) 3h 15min
4) 3h 
5) 15min 10sec
6) 15min 
7) 10sec
```

i'm getting values from **`systemctl status cassandra | awk '/(Active: active)/{print $9, $10,$11}'`** Now storing it's value in variable A,like

```
A=$(systemctl status cassandra | awk '/(Active: active)/{print $9, $10,$11}'
```

now A has input as 3 day 18h or 3 day etc. More examples-

**A=3 day 18h or 3 day or 3h 15min or 3h or 15min 10sec or 15min or 10sec**

now take different values of A, and parse in seconds.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve could be done directly in `awk` using the following line :

```
$ systemctl status cassandra | awk '/(Active: active)/{s=$6" "$7;gsub(/-|:/," ",s); print systime() - mktime(s)}'
```

This will give you the running time directly based on the start-time and not on the approximated running time printed by `systemctl`.

If this approach is not working then I suggest to use the `date` command to do all the parsing. If you can change the `h` by `hour` in your examples, then you can do the following :

```
$ date -d "1970-01-01 + 3day 18hour 15min 16sec" +%s
324916
```

If you cannot, then I suggest the following. If duration is stored in the variable `$duration`, then you do

```
$ date -d "1970-01-01 + ${duration/h/hour}" +%s
```

Having spaces between the numbers and the strings `day`, `h`,`min` or `sec` does not matter.

The idea of this is that you ask `date` to compute everything for you as `%s` returns the unix time since 1970-01-01 in seconds.

> **`man date`:**
>      `%s`     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

Comment: **$ systemctl status cassandra | awk '/(Active: active)/{s=$6" "$7;gsub(/-|:/," ",s); print systime() - mktime(s)}'** -- there is something wrong in gsub part...above command is producing the system time in epoch

Comment: @ParulChourasia I currently don't have access to a unix/linux box. What is printed if you print `s`?

Comment: i figured it out @kvantour...the problem was the field selection in the command. icorrected the command below:
`$ systemctl status cassandra | awk '/(Active: active)/{s=$7" "$8;gsub(/-|:/," ",s); print (systime() - mktime(s))}'`

earlier S prints **Fri 2018 04 27**. time was not getting extracted.

Comment: @ParulChourasia: I'm glad it worked out and you found the solution. I hope this is what you were after. Enjoy your day.

Answer (score 0):

The given value of `A` is<sup>*</sup>:

```
A="3day 3day/3h 15min/3h/15min 10sec/15min/10sec"
```

To compute `A` in seconds you can use bash's parameter expansion:

```
A=${A//day/*86400}                                                       
A=${A//h/*3600}                                                          
A=${A//min/*60}                                                          
A=${A//sec/*1}                                                           
A=${A//\//+}                                                             
A=${A// /+}                                                              
echo "A = $A"                                                            
echo $A | bc
```

Output:

```
A = 3*86400+3*86400+3*3600+15*60+3*3600+15*60+10*1+15*60+10*1            
542720
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Note here I changed the original value of `A` as provided by the OP. From

```
3 day/3 day/3h...
```

to

```
3day 3day/3h... # the rest is the same as OP's.
```

Answer (score -1):

Using awk to `s/h/hours/` and to launch `date  +"%s" -d "1970-01-01 GMT +"` to parse the time strings and to count the seconds:

```
$ awk '{
    sub(/h/,"hours")                                          # date no eat h
    $1=""                                                     # remove $1
    "date +\"%s\" -d \"1970-01-01 GMT + " $0 "\"" | getline s # date
    print s 
}' file
324000
259200
11700
10800
910
900
10
```

for the data:

```
$ cat file
1) 3 day 18h
2) 3 day
3) 3h 15min
4) 3h 
5) 15min 10sec
6) 15min 
7) 10sec
```

Comment: can you please explain the flow

Comment: Read a record, for example `1) 3 day 18h`. Replace `h`with `hours`(for `date`) and remove `1)` ie `$0==" 3 day 18hours"`. Then execute `date +"%s" -d "1970-01-01 GMT + 3 day 18hours"` and store seconds to `s` and output. 1970-01-01 GMT is 0 s for `date` and we add given time to it.

Comment: If the times are in `$9 $10 $11`, you could `var=$9" "$10" "$11; sub(/h/,"hours",var)` and so on.